# xcode I want to change the first xib on launch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, xib

I created an IPhone app, then I had to convert it to IPad app. Now, I added a new Objective-C Class which includes XIB, .M and .H files. and I want that new XIB file to be shown on launch.

my new created files are named PhotoViewController. If I choose that file to be launched, emulator shows black screen. If I choose MainWindow-iPad file, I see Hello_SOAPViewController file launched. It is very weird.

How can I fix this mess? I want PhotoViewController to be started on launch.

Please take a look at the image below. You can see my project files and the project setup screen.
[image]

Comment: set self.window.rootViewController = PhotoViewController; in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in appDelegate.

Comment: See the error message. The root view controller is not set properly, for whatever reason. As Girish has said, you can fix that programmatically in didFinishWithLaunching in your appDelegate.

Comment: plz put the comment in answer @Girish

Comment: @AhmedZ. I had added the code in answer. thx...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you convert app in to Universal:-

[image]

you have create Two Different `XIB` with same Custom Class. like bellow image:-

iphone->xib-select fileOwner

[image]

Now Create new xib for Ipad ite name PhotoViewController_ipad. Now just open it new created XIB-->click on File Owner---> there is look like:-

[image]

its right n side Custom class blank put there **PhotoviewCintroller**

and connect file owner to View

[image]

Now you have two Xib with same class One for Iphone and Other for Ipad now  you can achive this by using coding like bellow way:-

Fist you need to check its a Iphone or Ipad while app load in Delegate.m file:-

`#define isiPhone  (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == 0)?TRUE:FALSE`

**yourApplicationAppDelegate.h class**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class PhotoViewController;

@interface yourApplicationAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) PhotoViewController *viewController;

@end
```

**yourApplicationAppDelegate.m class**

```
#import "yourApplicationAppDelegate.h"

#import "PhotoViewController.h"
#define isiPhone  (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == 0)?TRUE:FALSE 
#define isiPhone5  ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)?TRUE:FALSE

@implementation yourApplicationAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        // Override point for customization after application launch.


        if (isiPhone) {

            if (isiPhone5) 
                {
                    self.viewController = [[PhotoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PhotoViewController_iphone5" bundle:nil];     
                }
                else
                {
                    self.viewController = [[PhotoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PhotoViewController_iphone" bundle:nil];
                }

        }else{
             self.viewController = [[PhotoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PhotoViewController_ipad" bundle:nil];

        }



        self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
    }
```

**EDIT**
One more think is that if you also code for iphone5 so you can also check with 
`#define isiPhone5  ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)?TRUE:FALSE` as i edited my answer

Comment: yourApplication Appdelegare.m didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method as i mention in Answer

Comment: same thing happens. black screen appears

Comment: Pleae you do not select any main window from ipad development window. is consider as a blanck there selection.see you have to two diffrent Xib with same class one is for Ipad and other is for iphone with same class

Answer (score 2):

1) Allocate the `PhotoViewController` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in `appDelegate` file.

2) set `self.window.rootViewController = PhotoViewController;`

Comment: only self.window.rootViewController = PhotoViewController; is not Enough they must check first device is Iphone or Ipad. then they must set Relevant Nib of ipad or iphone.

Comment: @NitinGohel I didn't consider device.